# Проблема с процедурой интеграции с унаследованной базой данных

Tags: django, postgresql

Есть проект на Python. Пытаюсь, используя функцию  inspectdb, произвести процедуру интеграции с унаследованной базой данных в Django 2.0.6. B итоге получаю ошибку:

```
# Unable to inspect table 'temp_asp_pers_data'
# The error was: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 3:                 indexname, array_agg(attname ORDER BY rnum),...
                                                     ^

# Unable to inspect table 'temp_aspirant_email'
# The error was: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 3:                 indexname, array_agg(attname ORDER BY rnum),...
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в несовместимости версий PostgreSQL и Django.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

> syntax error at or near "ORDER"
>
> array_agg(attname ORDER BY rnum)

Ошибка явно идёт от парсера SQL в `postgresql`. Поддержка сортировки данных для функций группировки была реализована в релизе 9.0.

Очевидно версия вашей базы более старая и код проекта это не учитывает. Проверьте требуемую минимальную версию для inspectdb. А так же запланируйте обновление СУБД. Все версии PostgreSQL до версии 9.4 EOL, в течении полугода 9.4 станет EOL, а у вас что-то ещё более старое стоит.